# What '--cache, --maxpeers' settings should I use for geth nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum

I start my geth nodes with `--cache=2048 --maxpeers=50` parameters, but I'm not sure about it.

What should I use for servers with 8/16/32G RAM?

Can the higher amount of --maxpeers increase the speed of broadcasting my transactions?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule (and this applies to databases in general, not just to Geth), as long as cache is set to a value within a (fairly broad) sensible range, performance won't change much. This is doubly true on modern systems, where the OS has its own caching. 2GB looks sane, but the best way to tune it is just to try different values and measure performance.

A higher maxpeers value could potentially increase transaction propagation speed slightly (at the expense of increasing bandwidth requirements). But unless your maxpeers setting is already pathologically low (and transaction propagation is causing you problems), this may just be a way of wasting network bandwidth, and may make things worse if you're already bandwidth constrained.